# How to pass id from recycler view to fragment?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to pass id from my `recyclerview` item to fragment, but I have an `error: void com.example.taskapprealm.database.IRecyclerItemData.itemData(int)` on a `null` object reference.
Null reference is inside callback2 in `editButton` listener.
Inside editButton I have two callbacks for two interfaces. One calling the fragment and the second one should pass id to fragment. I no have an idea what is wrong.

ClickListener in Adapter:

```
holder.editButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           int position = holder.getAdapterPosition();
           callback.onEditClick(position);
           callback2.itemData(position);

           Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "TEST " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
   });
```

Constructor in Adapter:

```
 public MainAdapter(List<Task> tasks, IRecyclerItemClickListener callback, IRecyclerItemData callback2) {
   this.tasks = tasks;
   this.callback = callback;
   this.callback2 = callback2;
```

}

Interface:

```
    public interface IRecyclerItemData {

    void itemData(int position);
}
```

Method in Fragment:

```
@Override
public void itemData(int position) {
    Task task = tasks.get(position);
    taskID = task.getId();

}
```

Comment: How are you instantiating MainAdapter?

Comment: Everything looks fine. Add the code from where you are initializing the Adapter in your fragment

Comment: Show how you instantiated the MainAdapter class, the problem might be there

Comment: @kfir88 
This is what I have in MainActivity:  mainAdapter = new MainAdapter(tasks,this, callback2);
The callback2 is null. I don't how to set Adapter when I have two interfaces in constructor of Adapter

Comment: if you pass null as Callback2 value, the error shows to you is clear.. you  must do this:  mainAdapter = new MainAdapter(tasks,this, new IRecyclerItemData(){//implemement interface methode here...});

Comment: Ok I used your solution and it works, but I have another problem. I have null list in itemData method in Fragment. How to initialise list from adapter in fragment but without call callbacks?

Answer (score 0):

write OnClick code in onBindViewHolder method

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.editButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                callback.onEditClick(position);
                callback2.itemData(position);

                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "TEST " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Code is in onBindViewHolder. The problem is probably in initializing of adapter.